# ActiveMQ password EncryptionOperationNotPossibleExecption

Tags: java, encryption, activemq-classic

I have been trying to get password encryption working on ActiveMQ.
I am following the example put out by Redhat. [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/6.3/html/security_guide/password-encrypt). But when I start AMQ I get EncryptionOperationNotPossibleExecption

My question is Why?

I am on Win 10
AMQ 5.16.0
JDK 1.8.0.221

I am currently running AMQ from the command line but will ultimately have to run it as a service.
Here is what I have:
conf/activemq-security.xml is the same as the conf/activemq.xml that comes with the distribution.
I added the three beans that every example prescribes.

```
<bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration" 
class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
    <property name="passwordEnvName" value="ACTIVEMQ_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" /
</bean>                                                                        
<bean id="configurationEncryptor" 
    class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
</bean>    
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
   class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
    <property name="location" value="file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials- 
    enc.properties"/>
</bean>
```

I ran exactly like the example.

```
PS bin\activemq encrypt --password encrypt123 --input password1
```

I got back=ll2ltbcoSnOSw/3oc9sD9pBN5y7SzTiK
I placed that in conf/credentials-enc.properties

```
activemq.password=ENC(ll2ltbcoSnOSw/3oc9sD9pBN5y7SzTiK)
```

I set the environment

```
PS $env:ACTIVEMQ_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD='encrypt123'
```

I ran

```
PS bin/activemq start xbean:conf/activemq-security.xml
```

I get the error

```
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_221 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre
  Heap sizes: current=1005056k  free=989327k  max=1005056k
    JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\conf\login.config -Dactivemq.classpath=C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\conf;C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\../conf;C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\../conf; -Dactivemq.home=C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\.. -Dactivemq.base=C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\.. -Dactivemq.conf=C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\conf -Dactivemq.data=C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\data -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\data\tmp
Extensions classpath:
  [C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\lib,C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\lib\camel,C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\lib\optional,C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\lib\web,C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\lib\extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: C:\Users\qad3\apache-activemq-5.16.0\bin\..\data
Loading message broker from: xbean:conf/activemq-security.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@1e127982: startup date [Fri Aug 28 15:45:07 EDT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I found a similar question here on SO and the solution was to change the output (the encrypted data) from actual base64-encoding to hex encoding. See this link on jasypt-FAQs: http://www.jasypt.org/faq.html#i-keep-on-receiving-encryption-operation-not-possible

Answer (score 0):

That way it worked for me, need to export environment variable in terminal before starting it.(AMQ 5.15.13)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!-- schemaLocation add: spring and camel-spring.xsd   -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd 
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
  
  <!-- obligatorily export --password in lower case: bin\activemq encrypt --password encrypt123 --input password1  -->
  <bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
    <property name="passwordEnvName" value="ACTIVEMQ_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
  </bean>
                                                                     
  <bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
  </bean>  
    
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" /> 
      <property name="location" value="file:${activemq.conf}/credentials-enc.properties"/> 
  </bean> 
  
  <broker useJmx="true" persistent="false" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" >

 <!-- alter ManagementContext to false -->

    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>
 
 <!-- add kahaBD -->
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter> 
    
<!-- =============== -->
<!-- plugins tag removed-->
<!-- =============== -->

     <!-- your config transport -->
    <transportConnectors>
       <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
    </transportConnectors>


    <shutdownHooks>
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
    </shutdownHooks>
  </broker>

   <!-- Oracle connect  -->
    <bean id="requiredBeanForOracleAq" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"/>
    <bean id="connectionFactoryOracleAQQueue" class="oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory" factory-method="getQueueConnectionFactory"> 
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SID_DB)))</value>
        </constructor-arg> 
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.util.Properties">
            <value/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

  <!-- Oracle user -->
    <bean id="oracleQueueCredentials" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <ref bean="connectionFactoryOracleAQQueue"></ref>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>USER_DB</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="oracleQueue" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="oracleQueueCredentials"/>
    </bean>

  <!--  Create queues  -->
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"> 
        <route>
            <from uri="oracleQueue:queue:TAB_ORACLE_queues_AMQ"/>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:queues_AMQ"/>
        </route>
        <route>
            <from uri="activemq:queue:TAB_queuesOracle"/>
            <to uri="oracleQueue:queue:queues_ORacle"/>
        </route> 

    </camelContext>
    
  <!--  Use jetty.xml instead of jetty-demo.xml -->
  <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Should be a comment not an answer